# views not showing when placed into ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I dropped in my angular app into a new ruby on rails app. what i'm noticing is that no views are being rendered out. i only see the layout being rendered. also i'm not getting any errors. my 2 views (home.html and about.html) and list.json are located in the public folder. please let me know if you need any more code from the app.

i have my application layout as follows:

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
              <title></title>
              <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
              <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
              <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                  <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                      <button data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar" type="button">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      </button>
                      <a href="/home" class="brand"><img src="assets/tool-box.png" /> Dev Tool Chest</a>
                      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                          <li class="active">
                            <a href="/home">Home</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="">
                            <a href="./about">About</a>
                          </li>

                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">

            <div id="view" ng-view></div>

            </div>


            </body>
            </html>
```

i have my application controller as follows:

```
                class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
              protect_from_forgery

              def index
              render :layout => 'application', :nothing => true
              end
            end
```

I've made my JS asset pipeline as follows:

```
                //= require jquery
            //= require jquery_ujs
            //= require bootstrap
            //= require angularmin.js
            //= require angularstrap.min.js
            //= require toolsapp.js
```

the toolsapp.js looks like this

```
                    var tools = angular.module("tools", ['$strap.directives'])

                tools.config(function($routeProvider) {

                  $routeProvider.when('/home', {
                    templateUrl: 'home.html',
                    controller: 'HomeController'
                  });
                   $routeProvider.when('/about', {
                    templateUrl: 'about.html',
                    controller: 'AboutController'
                  });




                  $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' })

                });

                tools.controller("HomeController", function($scope, fetchData) {


                fetchData.then(function(data){
                    $scope.record = data;
                    $scope.typeahead = function(){
                    var allNames = [];
                    for(var i=0;i<$scope.record.length;i++){
                    allNames.push($scope.record[i].name)
                    }
                    return allNames;
                    }
                  });



                $scope.clearSearch = function(){
                    $scope.search = "";
                    $scope.name2 = "";
                    }
                $scope.name2 = "";
                $scope.search = "";



                });

                tools.controller("AboutController", function($scope) {
                });





                tools.factory('fetchData', ['$http', function($http){
                  var Url  = "list.json";
                  var list = $http.get(Url).then(function(response){
                     return response.data;
                  });
                  return list;
                }]);






                tools.filter('unique', function () {

                  return function (items, filterOn) {

                    if (filterOn === false) {
                      return items;
                    }

                    if ((filterOn || angular.isUndefined(filterOn)) && angular.isArray(items)) {
                      var hashCheck = {}, newItems = [];

                      var extractValueToCompare = function (item) {
                        if (angular.isObject(item) && angular.isString(filterOn)) {
                          return item[filterOn];
                        } else {
                          return item;
                        }
                      };

                      angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                        var valueToCheck, isDuplicate = false;

                        for (var i = 0; i < newItems.length; i++) {
                          if (angular.equals(extractValueToCompare(newItems[i]), extractValueToCompare(item))) {
                            isDuplicate = true;
                            break;
                          }
                        }
                        if (!isDuplicate) {
                          newItems.push(item);
                        }

                      });
                      items = newItems;
                    }
                    return items;
                  };
                });
```

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield And notice that you don't have a `yield` in your layout

Comment: Why are your views located in the public folder. Put them into the app/views folder.

Comment: i don't think i need it since i have the following in my controller:render :layout => 'application', :nothing => true

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for this is:

Create a home controller:

**home_controller.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def about
  end
end
```

Move your views to `app/views/home` folder.

Add following routes:

*routes.rb*

```
get 'about', to: "home#about"
root to: 'home#index'
```

Remove from `application_controller`:

```
def index
  render :layout => 'application', :nothing => true
end
```

And add a `yield` in your layout:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="view" ng-view>
    = yield
  </div>
</div>
```

So, your home and about views are gonna be rendered inside your layout when you go to localhost:3000 and localhost:3000/about.